Linking a Custom Global Action with Activity?
I created a New Global Action in Opportunity 'New Log a Letter' with custom 'Activity' fields (E.g. 'Letter Name', 'Stage', 'Date Letter Log Updated'). However, there are a couple of edits I'm keen to make, which I haven't worked out how to do.

Move 'New Log a Letter' next to 'Log a Call' on the 'Opportunity' page's 'Activity' highlights.



When I create/ edit a 'Log a Letter' entry, it doesn't show up under 'Activity', it only shows up under 'Chatter'. I'd like it to show up under 'Activity' instead.


The below displays the 'Global Action':

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated, with many thanks.

The Activity tab component can only contain quick actions that points to creating Tasks and Events (as well as Log A Call, Send Email). Global and object-specific quick actions, except for those related to creating tasks, creating events, and logging calls, are always displayed on the highlights panel similar to your screenshot.
Here is an article for reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0

Thank you for your help Tushar. This is really helpful insight.
